# Automatically Run a Command Every 5 Minutes

Tags: command-line

I'm very new to using Linux and especially with command line. I've managed to successfully get a Plex Media Server up and running but I need to run the following command every 5 minutes to sync with my Amazon Drive.

acd_cli sync

I've tried various different methods such as bash scripts and can't get it to work. I just need the command above to run every 5 minutes and it feels like there's an easy way which I don't know about.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

**Easy Method**

You can set up a bash script that loops forever executing that command then sleeping for 5 minutes.

Open a terminal and execute this command:

```bsh
sudo nano /usr/local/bin/amazon-sync
```

Then, type the following:

```bsh
#!/bin/sh  
while true  
do  
  acd_cli sync  
  sleep 300  
done
```

Press <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>o</kbd> to save

Press <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>x</kbd> to exit

Execute this command:

```bsh
sudo chmod +x /usr/local/bin/amazon-sync
```

When you start up your computer press <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>t</kbd> and type `amazon-sync` then minimize the terminal window.  Command will run once every 5 minutes (300 seconds).

Comment: There's a way to make it run at startup but last time I tried to do that I had to go into system recovery to undo what I did, but I know it is possible if you do it right.

Comment: To make it work at start-up you need a cronjob.  See my answer below.

Answer (score 26):

You can use

```
crontab -e
```

to create a user cron schedule.

The line you specifically need is

```
*/5 * * * * /home/YOU/backup.sh
```

In `backup.sh` add any commands you want to run, make sure the script is executable, i.e. `chmod +x backup.sh`

Have a look at

http://www.unixgeeks.org/security/newbie/unix/cron-1.html

Answer (score 12):

There's also `watch` command, if you need to show output on screen and clear automatically.

```
watch -n 300 acd_cli sync
```

Answer (score 1):

When you say 5 minutes, Do you mean 5 minutes or will you forget about the command In 5 minutes and leave It running Indefinitely

There's so many options to choose from, But I'll show you 4 clever ways to Implement this.

---

```
for (( i=0; i<=20; i++)); do 'acd_cli sync' $i ;sleep 300; done
```

> > This says that i Is 0, Then 0 Is less than 20, So It will minus 1 until It reaches 0. So It will run 20 times. Every 5 minutes

```
while true; do 'acd_cli sync'; sleep 300; done | at now +30 min
```

> > This says while true, do the command given every 5 minutes, Starting now for 30 minutes long, To run this command you'll need to Install at by running apt install at --assume-yes, Not exactly sure that this will work on a loop though

```
while true [ $i -lt 20 ]; do 'acd_cli sync' & i=$[$i+1];sleep 300; done
```

> > This command says, While $i remains lower than 20 do the Amazon Cloud Drive Command Line Interface you listed, Then i Is still i plus one on every occurrence of the command, Every 5 minutes forever

```
for i in $(seq 20); do 'acd_cli sync' $i; sleep 300; done
```

> > This says For the Input sequence 20 do the Amazon Cloud Drive sync, Every 5 minutes 20 times